# confused about $scope and controllers and $mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

so, I'm trying to use $mdDialog and can't seem to pass values into the controller

my call is this

```
function myCtrl($mdDialog) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.showModal = function(item) {

        $mdDialog.show({
              controller: modalController,
              controllerAs: 'controller',
              locals: { data: {value: item}},

              templateUrl: '/myModal.html',

              parent: angular.element(document.body)

            })

            .then(function(answer) {
              console.log("'#1",answer);
            }, function() {
              console.log("cancelled");
            });


    };
}

function modalController($scope,data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

showModal() is called from ng-click, passing in a value (ie ng-click="ctrl.showModal(10)" )

when I press the button, i get the following in the console ..

```
anonymous(expression, locals, later, ident)
```

where I actually expected to see {value: "10"}

how do I get the value of the data variable / property ?

thanks

**update#1**
if I add

```
 bindToController: true,
 foobar: true,
```

and change the controller definition to

```
function modalController($mdDialog) {
   var controller = this;
    console.log(controller.foobar,controller.locals);
}
```

I seem to be able to pass in any option specified in the call to $mdDialog

ie if I say xyz: "abc" then I can refer to controller.xyz and it is indeed "abc"

is this a valid thing ? it doesn't smell right ...

**update#2**

solved the original problem : I had specified modalController with

```
modalController.$inject['$scope','$controller']
```

by accident at the top of the file - so things were screwed.

I corrected this to be

```
modalController.$inject['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'data'];
```

I also had the wrong parameters passed to the function, which should be

```
function modalController($scope,$mdDialog,data)
```

so, my original question has been solved.

However, I am still interested in the update#1, when bindToController is used and I can set any property in the options

Comment: An explanation on bindToController: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Comment: thanks for that - makes a lot more sense now ;)